# How to detect when scope property is set in Angular directive link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a directive that needs to initialize some data based on values passed into it through the scope. The problem is that when I try and initialize the data in the link function, the passed in value isn't available yet. Is there anyway to only run the initialization when the passed in value is available? I thought about using a watch as in the following code but it seems messy (and doesn't seem to work anyway).

```
.directive('etMemberActivitySummary', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '<div>My template</div>',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            memberModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var watcher = scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return scope.memberModel
                },
                function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    if (value != null) {
                        console.log('Watch');
                        console.log(value);
                        watcher();
                        // Perform initialization based on scope.memberModel here
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}])
```

Is there a correct way to do this? If it helps, the passed in value is in itself retrieved from a web service.

Update 1

Turns out that if I put an ng-if="ctrl.memberModel" on the directive usage like the following and get rid of all the watch stuff, it works. Is this the best way to do this?

```
<et-member-activity-summary member-model="ctrl.memberModel" ng-if="ctrl.memberModel"></et-member-activity-summary>
```

Comment: ng-if creates a child scope, which may have unforseen circumstances. The first option is also better because you can unwatch it once memberModel is there. It's rather ok in current context but there may be better options in perspective. Not sure why it should be two-way binding. It may be better to import the service that provides `memberModel` directly and chain it with `then` if it's async.

Comment: @estus You're right, it may not need to be two way binding, I'll have to look at what the effect would be to just pass in the bits of memberModel I need. Can you clarify what you mean by the ng-if creating a child scope?

Comment: It's like wrapping a template with an extra directive with `scope: true`. ngIf creates a new inherited scope via transclusion, but the result is the same. Some scope interactions may not work as expected inside ngIf or ngFor.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Thanks for the info.